# filter array object using multiple value from array using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

the row users array looks like.

```
var users = [{name: 'John',address: 'USA',year:2010 },{name: 'John',address: 'USA',year:2011 },{name: 'John',address: 'USA',year:2012 },{name: 'John',address: 'USA',year:2013 },{name: 'John',address: 'USA',year:2014}];
```

the filter array is,

```
var filter_year = ['2010','2011','2012'];
```

how i can get the result array of filtered using years in filter_year,           i need to get result array like.

```
var users = [{name: 'John',address: 'USA',year:2010 },{name: 'John',address: 'USA',year:2011 },{name: 'John',address: 'USA',year:2012 }];
```

Comment: You'll have to iterate the json and push only those json objects whose year exist in `filter_year`

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code to get all users for given years.

```js
var filter_year = ['2010','2011','2012'],
    users = [{name: 'John',address: 'USA',year:2010 },{name: 'John',address: 'USA',year:2011 },{name: 'John',address: 'USA',year:2012 },{name: 'John',address: 'USA',year:2013 },{name: 'John',address: 'USA',year:2014}],
    filteredUsers = []
    allYears = filter_year.join("|");
    
    for(var user in users) { 
     if(allYears.indexOf(users[user].year) !== -1) {
        filteredUsers.push(users[user]);
       }
    }
    
    console.log(filteredUsers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just filter one array based on inclusion in the other array

```js
var users = [{name: 'John',address: 'USA',year:2010 },{name: 'John',address: 'USA',year:2011 },{name: 'John',address: 'USA',year:2012 },{name: 'John',address: 'USA',year:2013 },{name: 'John',address: 'USA',year:2014}];

var filter_year = ['2010','2011','2012'];

var result = users.filter( item => filter_year.includes(item.year+""));

console.log(result)
```

Note that the years are integers in one array, and strings in the other

Comment: Why did you use `item.year + ""` instead of `item.year.toString()`? Does it have any performance benefits?

Comment: @NisargShah - Don't know, but it probably doesn't matter performance-wise, they both do the same thing, coerce to a string